# ajax call, but screen still goes up

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have this:

View:

```
<div id="tabs-2">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditPhotos", "Account",
        new AjaxOptions()
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "Post",
        },
            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}





        ))

             //new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Photos</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)



                <form class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayItem)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayItem)

                    </div>

                    <div id="upload-choices">
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Image)

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-row">
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br />


                    <img width="200" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { id = Model.Id })">
                    <input type="file" name="file" />
                </form>
                <br />
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default pull-left" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <br /><br />
        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>

    </div>
```

and jquery:

```
 @section Scripts
    {
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#tabs").tabs();

                $("#tabs").tabs("select", window.location.hash);

                //var param = $(document).getUrlParam('selectedTab');
                //$('#tabs').tabs('select', param);
            });
        </script>
}
```

and controller action method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditPhotos(UserProfile userprofile,HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {


                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }

             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                 string username = User.Identity.Name;
                // Get the userprofile
                UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

                // Update fields
                user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(user.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);
                user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;

                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();

                return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-2");

             }
            return View(userprofile);       

        }
```

oke, I can save the photo, and when I save the photo the current tab stays the selected tab. But after save the screen goes up. So it seems a full post back and not a partial post back. Becauase before I save I see the three tabs. but after I save the tabs spring up. But I do a ajax call. so how can that?

Thank you

oke, I have it now like this:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#tabs").tabs();
                $(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
                $("#tabs").tabs("select", window.location.hash);

                //var param = $(document).getUrlParam('selectedTab');
                //$('#tabs').tabs('select', param);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

because if I do like this:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {

                $("#tabs").tabs();

                $("#tabs").tabs("select", window.location.hash);

                //var param = $(document).getUrlParam('selectedTab');
                //$('#tabs').tabs('select', param);
            });
```

I dont see the tabs anymore

and I have this:

```
<div class="pull-left">
            <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-default pull-left" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But what do you mean you dont see the Ajax call?

I have this:

```
<div id="tabs-2">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditPhotos", "Account",
        new AjaxOptions()
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "Post",
        },
            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}





        ))

             //new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Photos</h4>
                <hr />
```

etc...

but still the screen goes up, after save

ok, I have it now like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: resolveUrl("/Account/EditPhotos/"),
                type: "POST",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    //code after success

                },
                error: function (er) {
                    alert(er);
                }

            });


        });
```

but still the page goes up

If I do this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function(){

        $("#ajaxUploadForm").ajaxForm({
            iframe: true,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 1200000,
            async: false,
            beforeSubmit: function () {
                //Do something here if needed like show in progress message
            },
            //success: function (result) {
            //    alert("sucess"
            //    },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error uploading file");
            }
        });
        });
```

with:

```
 <div class="pull-left">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                        <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-default pull-left" />

                    </div>
                </div>
```

then nothing happens,

Comment: you have the ajax call just in your document.ready.  you need to put the ajax call in a click event like in my answer below that will trigger off of a button click.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your ajax code posted but your button is a submit button, not just a button.  you need to change that to

```
<input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-default pull-left" />
```

and in your script change the event to a click event

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function(){
    ...
```

Comment: how you are doing the ajax call is through the form which requires a post back, hence the page moving up.  To do an ajax call without post back see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload